# Dealing with smaller number of categories in the scoring data within (Py)Spark pipelines

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two chained Spark-ML pipelines (see the code below). The first is used for data preparation (string indexing -> imputing -> one-hot-encoding -> vector assembling), the second is used for model estimation (random forest classifier). The data wrangling pipeline produces the target vector, and sparse vector of features (that has 270 features in it).

I fit both consecutive pipelines on the training data. So far so good.

Next, I want to use the same pipeline in the scoring of unseen (=scoring) data. But, when I run the scoring data throught the data preparation pipeline, probably due to a lower amount of labels in some of the categorical variables of this new dataset, it produces fewer columns (perhaps due to one-hot-encoding). Thus, the vector assembler produces a narrower sparse vector (that has only 250 features), which yields and "IndexOutOfBoundsError" in the scoring pipeline (which is looking for index 252 which is not there).

Could you please you advise me a general strategy / best practice of how to circumvent this issue?

For some reason I thought that when you use '.transform' operation from the fitted pipeline, it will preserve the dimensions (simply filling the non-present columns with 0), but apparently that is not the case.

A) Fitting of pipelines using training 'df'

```py
stages_string_indexing = [StringIndexer(inputCol= c, outputCol= c+"_strIndex", handleInvalid = "keep") for c in variable_types['categorical']]

categorical_str = [c+"_strIndex" for c in variable_types['categorical']]
stage_imputer = Imputer(inputCols = categorical_str, outputCols = categorical_str, missingValue = -999)

stage_one_hot_encoding = [OneHotEncoder(inputCol= c, outputCol= c+ "_ohe") for c in categorical_str]

stage_vector_assembler_cat = VectorAssembler(inputCols = [c+ "_ohe" for c in categorical_str], outputCol= "features_cat")

pipeline_dataPrep_cat = Pipeline(stages= stages_string_indexing + [stage_imputer] + stage_one_hot_encoding + [stage_vector_assembler_cat])

stage_imputer_q = Imputer(inputCols = variable_types['quantitative'], outputCols = variable_types['quantitative'], strategy = "median")

stage_vector_assembler_q = VectorAssembler(inputCols = variable_types['quantitative'], outputCol= "features_q")

pipeline_dataPrep_q = Pipeline(stages= [stage_imputer_q, stage_vector_assembler_q])

stage_vector_assembler_all = VectorAssembler(inputCols = ['features_q', 'features_cat'], outputCol= "FEATURES")

pipeline_dataPrep = Pipeline(stages= [pipeline_dataPrep_cat,pipeline_dataPrep_q, stage_vector_assembler_all])

pipelineModel_dataPrep = pipeline_dataPrep.fit(df)
df = pipelineModel_dataPrep.transform(df)

modelling_data = df.select("TARGET", "FEATURES")
modelling_data.show()


stage_rf_classifier = RandomForestClassifier(labelCol = "TARGET", featuresCol = "FEATURES")

pipeline_rf = Pipeline(stages = [stage_rf_classifier])

# DEFINE CROSS-VALIDATION experiment
paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder() \
  .addGrid(stage_rf_classifier.numTrees, [20, 100]) \
  .addGrid(stage_rf_classifier.maxDepth, [2, 10]) \
  .build()

cross_validator_rf = CrossValidator(estimator = pipeline_rf
                          , estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid
                          , evaluator = BCE(labelCol = "TARGET"
                                            , rawPredictionCol = "probability"
                                            , metricName = "areaUnderROC")
                          , numFolds= 2)

# clock the model fitting:
print('Model fitting started at: '+ str(datetime.datetime.now()))
cv_rf = cross_validator_rf.fit(modelling_data_sample)
print('Model fitting fnished at: '+ str(datetime.datetime.now()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried what have described on a simple use case and I was not able to replicate the problem described above (so I am now really puzzled).

See my example below:

```
# ================================================
# TRAIN:
# ================================================

from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer, OneHotEncoder, VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline, Transformer

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(0, 1,"a", 1.2)
     , (1, 0, "b", 0.8)
     , (2, 1, "c", 7.3)
     , (3, 0,"a", 6.25)
     , (4, 0, "a", 4.53)
     , (5, 0, "c", 1.45)],
    ["id", "target","category","number"])

indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="category", outputCol="categoryIndex", handleInvalid = "keep")
ohe = OneHotEncoder(inputCol= "categoryIndex", outputCol= "categoryIndex_ohe")
vas = VectorAssembler(inputCols = ["id","categoryIndex_ohe","number"], outputCol= "features")

pipeline_dataPrep = Pipeline(stages= [indexer, ohe, vas])

pipelineTrans = pipeline_dataPrep.fit(df)
df_trans = pipeline_dataPrep.fit(df).transform(df).select('id','target','features')
df_trans.show()

from pyspark.ml.classification import RandomForestClassifier

# fit model:
rf = RandomForestClassifier(labelCol="target", featuresCol="features", numTrees=10)
pipeline_rf = Pipeline(stages= [rf])

pipelineModel = pipeline_rf.fit(df_trans)

# ================================================
# SCORE:
# ================================================

df_score = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(0, "a", 0.3)
     , (1, "a", 2.8)
     , (2, "a", 1.3)
     , (3,"a", 1.25)
     , (4, "d", 3.53)
     , (5, "a", 1.45)],
    ["id","category","number"])

df_score_trans = pipelineTrans.transform(df_score)
df_score_trans.select('id','features').show()

df_rf = pipelineModel.transform(df_score_trans)
df_rf.show()
```